# Recording audio that is playing on computer via terminal

Tags: linux, macos, lame

I am trying to record audio outputted from whatever i am listening to on my computer and save that to my desktop.

I am following this tutorial
http://jordilin.wordpress.com/2006/07/28/howto-recording-audio-from-the-command-line/

I have lame installed if i run 
which lame i get

```
/opt/local/bin/lame
```

So thats installed correctly but if i try and run the following command.

```
arecord -f cd -t raw | lame -x -r - out.mp3
```

I get the output below

```
-bash: arecord: command not found
Assuming raw pcm input file : Forcing byte-swapping
LAME 3.99.5 64bits (http://lame.sf.net)
Using polyphase lowpass filter, transition band: 16538 Hz - 17071 Hz
Encoding <stdin> to out.mp3
Encoding as 44.1 kHz j-stereo MPEG-1 Layer III (11x) 128 kbps qval=3
```

I get a mp3 file on my desktop that is 834 bytes but doesnt play anything i see

```
-bash: arecord: command not found
```

But when i google installing arecord i dont get anything useful back?

Could someone please point me in the right direction

Thanks

Oh yeah i am on a mac osx lion

Comment: A Linux solution for capturing audio is almost certainly not going to work on Mac OS X.

Comment: ah right ok ill quit trying to get this to work then thanks

Comment: Search SO for previous questions along these lines - I've seen a few questions about emulating Audio Hijack, WireTap, *et al* in the past.